# Push registration returns errorCode 0 and null error sometimes

Tags: codenameone

I recently started registering users for push

Sometimes, registration fails with a `0` `errorCode` and a `null` `error` (in `pushRegistrationError`)

What could this mean? Does it just mean that the user rejected the request for push permissions (always)?

Comment: That means we didn't get a value we can pass onward in those arguments. It's possible this maps to user cancellation but I can't guarantee that's always the case.